# How to verify Electrum signature in Linux?

Tags: gpg

I am trying to install https://electrum.org/#download for that I am following the instructions, but when I trying to verify the signature, I have the following error:

```
└─$ gpg --verify Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz.ThomasV.asc Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz                                                                                 2 ⨯
gpg: Signature made Mon 19 Jul 2021 09:22:29 PM MSK
gpg:                using RSA key 6694D8DE7BE8EE5631BED9502BD5824B7F9470E6
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(katya12㉿kali)-[/home/katya/soft/electrum]
└─$ gpg --import Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz.ThomasV.asc                                                                                                       2 ⨯
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

There is an instruction

```
On Linux, you can import that key using the following command: gpg --import ThomasV.asc.
```

But there is no ThomasV.asc file anywhere. Could you tell me how to verify the signature of last Electrum version for Linux?

**UPDATE:**
I have download the key from different source (which is not mentioned in instructions) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spesmilo/electrum/master/pubkeys/ThomasV.asc then tried to verify the signature with it with following error:

```
└─$ sudo gpg --import ThomasV.asc                                                                                                                        2 ⨯
[sudo] password for katya12: 
gpg: key 2BD5824B7F9470E6: "Thomas Voegtlin (https://electrum.org) <thomasv@electrum.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

┌──(katya12㉿kali)-[/home/katya/soft/electrum]
└─$ sudo gpg --verify ThomasV.asc Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz                                                                                                  2 ⨯
gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

You need to `gpg --import` public keys.
here is a list of [Electrum pubkeys](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/tree/master/pubkeys)

And then sign them with your own private key (Which means they are trusted by you)

in the end:

```
gpg --verify signature-of-file.asc file
```

Comment: how to sign with own private key?

Comment: @Catherine
 first import the right public key

```gpg --import  ThomasV.asc```

then generate a private key for yourself.

```$ gpg --generate-key```

and then sign the (trusted) public key with your own private key

```$ gpg --sign-key Thomas```

Comment: thank you! It does work, but one more question:  I do everything under root, because otherwise gpg said "gpg: no writable public keyring found: Not found" , could you tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: @Catherine You need to create a username with root access through ```sudo```.  You can also ask another question in this regard.

Comment: Do I really need to sign with my private key? Shouldn't importing and verifying be enough?

Answer (score -1):

The [download page](https://electrum.org/#download) has a [by several builders](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/tree/master/pubkeys) link.  When you click on that, it takes you to a GitHub page that includes the [ThomasV.asc](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/pubkeys/ThomasV.asc) file you are looking for.  That file link takes you to the "code" contained in said file, and you need to click the [Raw](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/raw/master/pubkeys/ThomasV.asc) button at the top of said code to download the file.  If clicking on that gives you the text in the browser, you need to use the File menu or right-click "Save As..." function to save the text in a file.  This file might be named ThomasV.asc.txt by your browser, but you can add .txt in the command line to import the signature if it is.  Once the signature is imported, you should be able to verify using the original command, but it may tell you the signature isn't trusted until/unless you mark the signature trusted.

Comment: Please read the update to my question

Comment: @Catherine - after downloading the correct public key, you succeeded with `gpg --import ThomasV.asc` where your import command previously had an incorrect "Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz."  Now you need to fix the verify command.  The correct command is `sudo gpg --verify Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz.asc` (no "ThomasV.asc" and add ".asc" to the file name).  To be clear, `ThomasV.asc` is the public key for encrypting messages to him and verifying signatures from him.  OTOH, `Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz.asc` is his signature for verifying that `Electrum-4.1.5.tar.gz` came from him and has not been tampered with.